# not able to check if inputted value is in list(tried as checking string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Im trying to check if the inputted value is a certain string, doing it directly as
`if var == 'str':`
didn't work so I tried this, where I check to see if its in a specified position of a list.

```
physics = list()
chemistry = list()
history = list()
geography = list()
comSci = list()
subjects = ['physics', 'chemistry', 'history', 'geography', 'comSci']
nameVar = None
subjectVar = None

for i in range(5):
    nameVar = input("enter the students name: ")
    subjectVar = input("enter the subject chosen: ")

    while subjectVar not in subjects:
        try:
            subjectVar = input("enter a valid subject: ")
        except:
            print("enter a valid subject!")

    if subjectVar.lower == subjects[0]:
        physics.append(nameVar)
    elif subjectVar.lower == subjects[1]:
        chemistry.append(nameVar)
    elif subjectVar.lower == subjects[2]:
        history.append(nameVar)
    elif subjectVar.lower == subjects[3]:
        geography.append(nameVar)
    elif subjectVar.lower == subjects[4]:
        comSci.append(nameVar)

print("physics:", len(physics), 'people')
print("chemistry:", len(chemistry), 'people')
print("history:", len(history), 'people')
print("geography:", len(geography), 'people')
print("comSci:", len(comSci), 'people')
```

please help

Comment: you forgot to call  `lower`: should be `subjectVar.lower()` (note the missing `()`). also `subjects = {'physics': [], 'chemistry': [], 'history': [], 'geography': [], 'comSci': []}` might te the better datastructure. this would allow you to write `subjects[subjectVar.lower()].append(nameVar)` instead of the long `elif` chain.

Comment: you are missing the brackets in call to lower: `subjectVar.lower()`

Comment: It should also be noted that `.lower()` is unnecessary here. If this condition `while subjectVar not in subjects:` is ever met then there won't be a need to convert to lowercase to compare.

Comment: `'Physics'.lower`  gives output like `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fb0a8c584b0>` this. So you need to call the method.

Answer (score -1):

As per `users comment` you can see the error is because of comparing a `first class objects` with `str object` which is always false. Everything is `okk` with your code, just call `lower function` as `subjectVar.lower() == ...`

### For more optimized code check out this code :

```
subjects = ['physics', 'chemistry', 'history', 'geography', 'comSci']
x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for i in range(5):
    nameVar = input("enter the students name: ")
    subjectVar = input("enter the subject chosen: ")

    while subjectVar not in subjects:
        try:
            subjectVar = input("enter a valid subject: ")
        except:
            print("enter a valid subject!")

    x[subjects.index(subjectVar)] += 1

print(x)
for i, j in zip(range(5), subjects):
    print(j, x[i], 'people')
```